# tcpdump strange udp line

Tags: udp, tcpdump

I've found a strange line in the `tcpdump` output. Normally UDP packets are dumped in the following form:

```
timestamp IP srcaddress.port > dstaddress.port: UDP, length packetlength
```

but this is just:

```
timestamp IP srcaddress > dstaddress: udp
```

note the missing port numbers, the lowercase `udp` and the missing packet length.

Does somebody know what's this?

Comment: Just `udp`, not `[|udp]`?  What does `tcpdump -h` print?

Comment: @GuyHarris: as you can see this was a long time ago.. not even sure how to reproduce it in a different environment..